# Locating button element in modal and/or new window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new in using selenium web driver. Can you help me which Element should I use? Here is the code.

```
<a class="btn btn-sm blue" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down "></i>
</a>
```

I've already tried the class which is `class="btn btn-sm blue"` and its xpath

```
//*[@id="grdEmails"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]/div/a
```

but none of this has been work.

I commit error whenever I run my script using C# language and it say "IllegalLocatorException". I've tried a lot of classes/xpath/id etc(which I know it doesn't appropriate to use just to work my script). Can somebody help me to solve this?

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement btnAction = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn btn-sm blue"));
btnAction.Click();
```

Comment: Can you give the full code you use for the findElement and the xpath, accoording to https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/IllegalLocatorException.html its because you are feeding the function an illegal format for the locator.

Comment: I recommend using [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firepath/) for [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to check your xpath and css selectors - it's quick, easy and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think the By.ClassName does not support spaces in the selector.
2. If the element is a new window, you first need to switchTo() the window, [see this for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298841/webdriver-csharp-c-sharp-cannot-switch-between-windows)

Try:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='btn btn-sm blue']"));
```

Or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'btn') and contains(@class, 'btn-sm') and contains(@class, 'blue')]"));
```

Comment: By.ClassName does support spaces but you must use "" instead of ''

 eg     public static By scrollbarValue = By.xpath("//div[@class='nav-drop-down show']/div");

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-sm blue']"));
button.click(); // Click on button or any other action which you want to perform on button
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class locator isn't working because that element has several different classes; they're separated by spaces in the html. If the best way to identify that element on your screen is by checking all the classes, then you can do with a css selector like this:

```java
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.btn.btn-sm.blue']"));
```

Notice the dots between the class names; that is telling webdriver to find an `a` element which has the class `btn` and has the class `btn-sm` and has the class `blue`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Finding element by css-selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.btn.btn-sm.blue']"));
```

Finding element by xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//a[@class="btn btn-sm blue"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Modal popup button click pass the element xpath
    public void modalPopClickButtonByXpath(String sChildXpath) {

        driver.switchTo().activeElement();
        waitUntilElementVisibleByXpath(sChildXpath);
        WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath(sChildXpath));
        button.click();
    }

// Checking for Visibility of element
    public void waitUntilElementVisibleByXpath(String sXpath) {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 180);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(sXpath)));
        }
```